# How to implement "read more" functionality

Tags: django, django-cms

I actually want to put some entries page in the front page, but I just want to show some lines of the entry with a "read more" button. I've found some websites designed in Django CMS could do it.
Can you show me how to implement theses functionalities?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic and flexible version is to store two fields per entry: A summary and a full text. On the front page, you would only show the summary, and on the dedicated page/onclick, you can show the full version.

You could of course come up with "optimisations" to reduce redundancy, usually involving some type of markup to denote "summary" section(s) which get automatically extracted out of your full text, but it adds parsing and complexity overhead, reduces flexibility, and is usually not worth it.

Comment: Thanks, I've thought about this solution but I don't know if it's the best practice!